# Repeat values in array until specific length

Tags: python, arrays, repeat

I need some kind of function or little tip for my problem.

So I got a list let's say
`[1,2,3,4]`
but I need this array to be longer with the same elements repeated so let's say I need an array of length 10 so it becomes:
`[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2]`

So I need to extend the list with the same values as in the list in the same order

```
returnString = the array or string to return with extended elements
array = the basic array which needs to be extended
length = desired length
```

EDIT:

```
returnString = ""
array = list(array)
index = 0
while len(str(array)) != length:
    if index <= length:
        returnString += array[index]
        index += 1
    else:
        toPut = index % length
        returnString.append(array[toPut])
        index += 1
return returnString
```

Comment: Divide the new length by the length of the list, and multiply the list that many times. If it doesn't divide equally, concatenate enough elements to get to the desired length.

Comment: @martineau Sorry, I edited the post! I hope it's clear, my code could be cleaner I know that!

Comment: Why are you converting the array to a string?

Comment: Why are you using strings at all, the question is about a list.

Comment: @Barmar as my output wasn't correct I tried to use other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to iterate repeatedly over the list, and take as many values as you want.

```
from itertools import cycle

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myiter = cycle(lst)
print([next(myiter) for _ in range(10)])
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

You can also use it to extend the list (it doesn't matter if you append to the end while you are iterating over it, although removing items would not work).

```
from itertools import cycle

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
myiter = cycle(lst)
for _ in range(6):
    lst.append(next(myiter))
print(lst)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is simple with `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
output = list(islice(cycle(input), 10))
```

---

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I see that you can use it for in-place extension also `input.extend(islice(cycle(input), 6))` (see also my answer where I `append` to a list using `cycle`, but I didn't think of `islice` until you mentioned it)

Comment: Absolutely, although I don't think OP wanted to do that

Comment: Question was a little ambiguous because it says "So I need to extend the list..." but then has some code involving a new list.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be:

Iterate over the desired `length - len(x_lst)`, So you have `10 - 4 = 6` (new elements to be added). Now since the list element should repeat, you can append the `x_lst` elements on the go by the indices (`0,1,2,3,4,5`).

```
x = [1,2,3,4]

length = 10

for i in range(length - len(x)):
    x.append(x[i])

print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: This works, but it's confusing *why* it works.

Comment: @Barmar something that came into my mind on the go! hah

Comment: The answer would be improved with some explanation.

Comment: This is quite clever, but not necessarily only in a good sense.

Comment: The confusing thing is that this depends on the fact that you're indexing the same list that you're appending to. Otherwise, `x[i]` would eventually be out of range.

Comment: Otherwise, yes.

Comment: `x += islice(x, length - len(x))` and `x.extend(islice(x, length - len(x)))` also seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n = 10
lst =[1,2,3,4]
new_lst = [lst[i%len(lst)] for i in range(n)]
print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumOfValues = int(input("Number of Values: "))
List1 = [1,2,3,4]
List2 = []
Count = 0
while len(List2) < NumOfValues:
    List2.append(List1[Count])
    Count += 1
    if Count > len(List1) - 1:
        Count = 0
print(List2)
```

Comment: This will create nested lists.

Comment: This won't work when the result length isn't a multiple of the original length.

Comment: His original list has 4 elements, he wants 10 elements in the result.

Comment: You can't loop 2.5 times.

Comment: If it really were an integral number of repeats you wouldn't need the loops, just `List2 = List1 * NumOfRepeats`

Comment: Ok il make a better one

Comment: @Barmar that satisfy your expectations?

Comment: It works now, although it seems overly complex compared to other solutions.

Comment: Overly complex is my middle name

Answer (score 0):

I will show a tip to you:

If you have this `array [1,2,3,4]` so you can create a separated `newArray` that get this value and fill the `newArray` with this repeated values.
How? Loop! I think `for` can do this to you, just point the `array` and `newArray` to it knows which it will fill.

Answer (score 0):

First multiply the list by the number of times it needs to be repeated. If that's not the desired length, extend it with the appropriate slice of the list.

```
old_len = len(original)
new_len = 10
result = original * new_len // old_len
if new_len % old_len != 0:
    result += original[:new_len % old_len]
```